# D3.js multigraph: Output Relative Y Value of a Slider Value on the X-Axis, and match to SVG point location

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graph

I have a 3 line graph processed from a .tsv file into this semi-interactive line-graph: http://infinitepartycles.com/plotGraphMultipleTSV/

Code here:

http://codepen.io/ferret/pen/BoxKyX

You'll notice the Y values markers "matching" to the X values are wrong; that white # is the printout of < y(value) >.

I want it to output the relative Y value to whatever the slider value is, but when I dig into the array for any line, I get undefined...Any ideas?

Sidenote: the lines output Here:

```
var p1 = city.append("path") //Add the 3 coloured lines for transport type
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d.name; }) // ID of transport type
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); }); //data of all Y values
```

Why can't I get a value if I console.log(d) here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making your brushed event too complicated.  It could be re-written as:

```
function brushed() {
    var value = brush.extent()[0].toFixed(0);

    if (d3.event.sourceEvent) { // not a programmatic event
      value = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]).toFixed(0);
      brush.extent([value, value]);
    }

    handle.attr("cx", x(value));
    if (value <= 1) value = 1;

    circleBus
      .attr("opacity", 1)
      .attr("cx", x(value))
      .attr("cy", y(transports[0].values[value-1].people));

    circlePlane
      .attr("opacity", 1)
      .attr("cx", x(value))
      .attr("cy", y(transports[1].values[value-1].people));      

    circleTrain
      .attr("opacity", 1)
      .attr("cx", x(value))
      .attr("cy", y(transports[2].values[value-1].people));
}
```

See example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nyvwsAYNs0A4Izk5IFKZ?p=preview).